# Wordpress Logo Slider Javascript Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, conflict

Working on the following site and I can't figure out why the logo slider at the bottom won't work: http://tinyurl.com/7sev9cl It only works when I'm logged into the site, but not when I'm logged out.

I'm pretty sure it's a JS conflict, but I haven't worked with JS at all. Here's what the console said:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.logicmanager.com/wp-content/plugins/newstastic-post-slider/css/join.css?ver=4.0
[cycle2] --c2 init-- lgs_jquery.cycle2.js?ver=4.0:602
[cycle2] slides: > li (string) lgs_jquery.cycle2.js?ver=4.0:602
[cycle2] speed: 600 (number) lgs_jquery.cycle2.js?ver=4.0:602
[cycle2] prev: #next (string) lgs_jquery.cycle2.js?ver=4.0:602
[cycle2] next: #prev (string) lgs_jquery.cycle2.js?ver=4.0:602
[cycle2] timeout: 8000 (number) lgs_jquery.cycle2.js?ver=4.0:602
[cycle2] fx: scrollHorz (string) lgs_jquery.cycle2.js?ver=4.0:602
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.logicmanager.com/img/global/gradient/h300.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Does that mean that the file is not in the suggested place, or is there a conflict? I have no idea what I'm doing so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have some 404 errors, one of which is the CSS file for the slider. Were those assets uploaded as user content and not available pre-login?

Comment: The JS files within the plugin are "inactive" when editing the plugin via the Wordpress editor. However, the .php file that calls for them is active. It's strange.

Comment: Should there be code in http://www.logicmanager.com/wp-content/plugins/newstastic-post-slider/js/front.js?ver=1.0?

Comment: Yes, but I'm referring to the logo slider and yes there is content in those JS files. They're just inactive. Not sure if it's the PHP calls or what but they're not being used.

Comment: I don't know what "inactive" means here.

Comment: They are not being used by the plugin for some reason. Next to the file name in the plugin editor it indicates whether the file is active or inactive. The plugin is not currently making any changes to the site's display. a plugin may be automatically deactivated if it contains syntax or other fatal errors that would otherwise bring the site down.

Comment: I have included the PHP file with calls for the Jquery here in JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/petey88/1ed5aprm/